# How can I convert excel to json and write to json file programmatically in cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, excel, promise, cypress

I had written the code to read the excel file into json, but not able to read it as expected. It return the array of each row. Can someone help me read the data and write it to json file correctly. Thanks in advance. Below is my code:

**plugins/index.js file**

```js
const xlsx = require("node-xlsx").default;
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("task", {
    parseXlsx({ filePath }) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const jsonData = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
          resolve(jsonData);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**spec.js file**

```js
describe('API', () => {
    it('readf', () => {
        cy.parseXlsx("/Cypress/cypress/fixtures/data.xlsx").then(
            (jsonData) => {
                const rowLength = Cypress.$(jsonData[0].data).length
                for (let index = 0; index < rowLength; index++) {
                    console.log(jsonData[index].data)
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

I want the json output and write to json file as below:

```js
{
    "Sheet1": [
        {
            "Username": "user1",
            "password": "password1"
        },
        {
            "Username": "user2",
            "password": "password2"
        },
        {
            "Username": "user3",
            "password": "password3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you do not have larger set of data in excel and if it is just username and password data, then why can't you put the data in JSON itself and why are you making things complex. I am just trying to understand your use case.

Comment: @SrinuKodi, This is just the example file. But, in real i have excel file which contains more than 7 columns. So, just for example the i need json like:

`{
    "Sheet1": [
        {
            "Username": "user1",
            "password": "password1",
            "firstname":"test1",
            "lastname":"gender",
            "age":"20",
            "gender":"M/F",
            "location":"abc"
        }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 3):

For converting Excel sheets into JSON (and back), I use SheetJS's [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).

```js
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

// read file
let workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename);

// read first sheet (identified by first of SheetNames)
let sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

// convert to JSON
let json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
```

Keep in mind, especially if running a sever app, `xlsx` uses blocking methods and will cause I/O waits on your process thread. Better run this async in a [fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options).

Comment: Thanks, for the approach but i am not dealing with the server app. So, i am getting the error of readFileSync. So could you suggest some other way.

Comment: I think my approach should work well with non-server app. What error are you getting?

Comment: Well, it should be :) Are we using the same library ([xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx), not node-xlsx)? Post more code.

Comment: I tried with xlsx and it shows _fs.readFileSync is not a function

Comment: That's weird. What environment are you using, node? Post more code. Alternatively, read the file manually and parse it thru `XLSX.read(buffer)`.

Comment: I'd advise using newer node, current LTS ver is 12.18.2. Post at least minimal reproducible code of you data-parsing method.

Comment: I tried after upgrading and it throws same error. Regarding code i had written the same code in my sample_spec.js file  which you posted

Comment: Do you suppose me to guess how you implemented this into your code? :D

Comment: `const XLSX = require('xlsx')

describe('API', () => {
    it('readf', () => {
  try{
   let workbook = XLSX.readFile("/Cypress/cypress/fixtures/data.xlsx"); 
   let sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
   let json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
   console.log(json)
  }catch(e){
   throw Error(e)
  }
    }
)`

This is what i have written in my spec.js file

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/3z5NsXYE) works just fine in my test env. Maybe try running it plain without mocha functions? (without `describe` and `it` block).

Comment: It reads everything and store in json file as string parameter. Actually i have json object in one cloumn which i need to be as
Read and write in json file as: 
{
"Name":"abcd",
"Addr": {
"Country":"test",
"Test am": [
{
"City1":"c1",
"City2":"c2"
}
]
}
}

Comment: For parsing JSON object out of a string, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). For parsing a column on each row, I'd recommend [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array with a method which parses the column. If you need more help with this, post it as a new question with more specifics :)

Comment: For command line, I wrote a xlsx / json / ods / markdown table reader writer in Rust.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ImportItemsInput').change(function (e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
        var sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
        let json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot directly convert excel to JSON and read it in your code. As the readFileSync hits the browser and it is a server based function.

To overcome this issue please follow the solution provided by me in the below repository.
"https://github.com/Achudan/ExcelToJsonConverterForCypress"

(IT WORKED GOOD FOR OUR TEAM AND IT'S SIMPLE SOLUTION RATHER THAN WRITING A SEPARATE EXCEL TO JSON CONVERTER)

Run the node app in a port and make cy.request in your Cypress command.

Detailed explanation is given in Readme of above github link.